# Mac OS X - Why does netstat give error "got %d twice"?

Tags: c, macos, freebsd, netstat, darwin

I'm trying to figure out why `netstat` on my Mac OS X computer prints stuff like "got 4 twice".

For example:

```
$ netstat | head -15
Active Internet connections
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q  Local Address          Foreign Address        (state)    
[...]
tcp4       0      0  localhost.56892        localhost.26164        ESTABLISHED
got 4 twice
got 16 twice
got 1 twice
got 4 twice
got 4 twice
got 8 twice
```

The message is printed by netstat's [inet.c](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/network_cmds/network_cmds-356.8/netstat.tproj/inet.c), in the function `protopr` which basically does the following:

- Calls `sysctlbyname(3)` using e.g. `net.inet.tcp.pcblist_n` to get a list of PCBs (I guess?)
- Loops through the results, collecting pointers to various structs, whose type is called an `xgn_kind`
- It sets a bit for each `xgn_kind` it has seen.  If it sees any of them twice, it complains with the message `"got %d twice"`.

I've cut out the relevant parts of the code:

```
void
protopr(uint32_t proto,   /* for sysctl version we pass proto # */
    char *name, int af)
{
  /* ... */

  if (sysctlbyname(mibvar, 0, &len, 0, 0) < 0) {
    if (errno != ENOENT)
      warn("sysctl: %s", mibvar);
    return;
  }

  /* ... */

  for (next = buf + ROUNDUP64(xig->xig_len);
       next < buf + len;
       next += ROUNDUP64(xgn->xgn_len))
  {
    /* ... */

    if ((which & xgn->xgn_kind) == 0) {
      which |= xgn->xgn_kind;
      /* ... */
    } else {
      printf("got %d twice\n", xgn->xgn_kind);
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

My question is, finally:

Why is this happening?  Is it faulty data coming back from `sysctl`?  Is the loop above incorrect, i.e., can `sysctl` actually return several structs per kind?

Note that I'm running Mac OS X -- and the code is indeed a little bit different from [FreeBSD's](http://svnweb.freebsd.org/csrg/usr.bin/netstat/inet.c?view=markup).

Comment: When I run the command `netstat | head -15`, I do not get any such error message.  Does the same error appear if you just do `netstat`?

Comment: @EricLeschinski Yes, it has nothing to do with `head`.

Comment: Example output from netstat at http://pastebin.com/GkXrVBL7

Comment: Do you get the same errors if you run the command `netstat -A`?  Perhaps using different options might coax a new clue out of netstat: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/netstat.1.html

Comment: `lsof` as root may help you find socket files that have a protocol blocks associated with them.  Does `lsof -i tcp -nP` give you any errors?  Down near the bottom of this page, are examples that may help you find the bad sockets: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/lsof.8.html

Comment: No, `lsof` doesn't give any errors.

Comment: Can you provide the output of "sysctl -A | grep net.inet.tcp.pcb"

Comment: @steve Unfortunately, I rebooted and the problem went away.  I noticed that /dev/null wasn't writeable, so I just rebooted.  I guess many things were wrong on my system, and I can't reproduce it now.